# Building FFMPEG with Android Project

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I have generated ffmpeg binaries and setup NDK with my Android Studio I have also generated static files of ffmpeg. I am new with Android NDK I need help with building ffmpeg with my Android Project can anyone guide me to do so.

Here is the [image: screenshot] of the generated files.

This is my Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(ANDROID_NDK)/sources/ffmpeg-3.3
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Os -fpic -marm -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon
LOCAL_MODULE := MyFFmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := arm/videoKit.c arm/ffmpeg.c arm/ffmpeg_filter.c arm/ffmpeg_opt.c arm/cmdutils.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libavdevice libavformat libavfilter libavcodec libavutil libswresample libswscale
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,ffmpeg-2.2.3/android/arm)
```

Comment: where you stuck? doesn't clear

Comment: @KishoreJethava need to create a Java Wrapper and compile those files with my Android project

Answer (score 0):

You can create binary for `FFmpeg` from this [tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) and also

[WritingMinds](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) has good and easy to use library to fulfil video processing task